# Se dice "los libros FUERON abiertos"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, cópulas

> Al iniciarse el juicio, los libros fueron abiertos.

¿Porqué "ser" en vez de "estar"?

https://www.bible.com/bible/1637/DAN.7.NVI — v. 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with Diego's answer, the verb **ser** is being used there because the sentence is in **passive voice**. You can not use any other verb to form that voice in Spanish, as you can see [here](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/es/gramatica-de-aprendizaje-espanol/the-passive).

Active voice

> Al comienzo del juicio, abrieron los libros (ES)
> At the beginning of the trial, they opened the books (EN)

Passive voice

> Al comienzo del juicio, los libros fueron abiertos (ES)
> At the beginning of the trial, the books were **opened** (EN)

To reflect what Diego described in his answer in English the difference is very subtle

> Al comienzo del juicio, los libros estuvieron abiertos (ES)
> At the beginning of the trial, the books were **open** (EN)

In both languages those sentences seems to imply that at some point during the trial, somehow the books were **closed** or were found **closed**.

Comment: Yes, it is passive. Someone should bother to mention that in Spanish fueron abiertos = se abrieron. That is very useful for learners.

Comment: La oración esta en voz pasiva precisamente porque utiliza el verbo Ser", y para indicar el sentido que únicamente se puede expresar, en estos casos, con ese verbo "Ser", y no, por contra, el que se obtiene al utilizar el verbo "Estar". No es lo mismo "Estuvieron abiertos" que "Fueron abiertos". Al lado queda la manera de utilizar las construcciones ("Ser" - forma pasiva), para indicar esos distintos sentidos de "Ser y Estar", y que ahí no he entrado.

Comment: Hola, creo que la pregunta era ¿Por qué "ser" en vez de "estar"?. La cuestión no era de base gramatical. Solo me limitó a comparar el V. "Ser" con el V. "Estar". Si la construcción hubiera sido "Los libros es-tuvieron abiertos", es decir con el verbo "Estar", la oración cambiaría su sentido. El hecho de que la frase este en pasiva y se utilice por tanto el verbo "Ser", como es natural, no invalida el sentido del V. "Ser" en forma pasiva., "Abrir" V pronominal "abrirse" "se abren "se abrieron los libros" (f. reflexiva). La cuestión es, "Ser" y "Estar". "Fueron" y "Estuvieron" y no otra.

Answer (score 0):

DANIEL

**Al iniciarse el juicio,
Los libros fueron abiertos**.

Verbo ser y estar

Al utilizar un verbo u otro la interpretación varia;

- fueron ( 3ª ps. plural - pretérito perfecto simple)
- estuvieron ( 3ª ps. plural- pretérito perfecto simple)

Si utilizas el verbo estar "Al iniciarse el juicio los libros es-tuvieron abiertos" Se entiende que cuando se inicio el juicio, llegados allí los presentes los libros ya se encontraban abiertos.

Sin embargo, si decimos "*Al iniciarse el juicio, los libros fueron abiertos*". Se interpreta que en origen estaban cerrados y que fue en ese momento, al iniciarse el juicio cuando los libros "fueron" abiertos, no *estaban* abiertos hasta el momento que *se* abrieron.

**Ser**

origen
destinación
propiedad
la hora
frase impersonal
características
suceso social

**Estar**

la salud
una condición
localización
contrariedad
énfasis

Comment: Hmmm.  I would have thought "estaban" for the first meaning and "estuvieron" for the second.  To me (not a native speaker), "fueron" implied that openness became at that moment a permanent characteristic.  Always learning …

Comment: A partir de ahí se vuelve permanente, hasta que se vuelvan a cerrar ó el juicio acabe, que será por tiempo. Igual si eres moreno, permanente, y vas a la peluquería y te conviertes en rubio, tu nueva permanencia hasta que cambies de nuevo será la de ser rubio.

Comment: Lo entiendo; gracias.

Comment: Se puede decirle que "fueron abiertos" es igual que: "se abrieron".

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión, la forma que me parece más natural (y así lo atestiguan varias traducciones de la *Biblia*) es

> Al iniciarse el juicio, (se) abrieron los libros.